# Simple math formula bringing back Null/Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling with what should be a simple formula in SQL, however it's proving to be difficult as it's bring back Zero/Null.

The formula should bring back the difference from one number to another

The simple line is -

```
ISNULL ((b.BilledSupplies - b2.BilledSuppliesPreviousMonth) / nullif (b2.BilledSuppliesPreviousMonth, 0) * 100, 0) AS [BilledSuppliesDifference]
```

This is in the select Syntax as follows

```
SELECT Isnull (b2.billedsuppliespreviousmonth, 0)                           AS 
       [BilledSuppliesPreviousMonth], 
       Isnull (( b.billedsupplies - b2.billedsuppliespreviousmonth ) / 
                       NULLIF (b2.billedsuppliespreviousmonth, 0) * 100, 0) AS 
       [BilledSuppliesDifference], 
       UnbilledSupplies = Isnull (u.unbilledsupplies, 0), 
       Isnull (u2.unbilledsuppliespreviousmonth, 0)                         AS 
       [UnbilledSuppliesPreviousMonth], 
       Isnull(( u.unbilledsupplies - u2.unbilledsuppliespreviousmonth ) / 
                     NULLIF (u2.unbilledsuppliespreviousmonth, 0) * 100, 1) AS 
       [UnbilledSuppliesDifference], 
       Isnull (Round(b.billedsupplies * 100.0 / 
                     ( b.billedsupplies + u.unbilledsupplies ), 1), 100.00) AS 
       [PercentageBilled]
```

If we take the original line from above - `ISNULL ((b.BilledSupplies - b2.BilledSuppliesPreviousMonth) / nullif (b2.BilledSuppliesPreviousMonth, 0) * 100, 0) AS [BilledSuppliesDifference]` - this is running from the following

```
Unbilled AS
(   SELECT  c.CreatedDate
            --s.ProfileClass
            --c.BillingTier
            ,FromDate = MIN(c.FromDate)
            ,ToDate = MAX(c.ToDate)
            ,Days = SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, c.FromDate, c.ToDate) + CONVERT(INT, c.FirstCharge))
            ,EAC = MAX(c.EstimatedAnnualConsumption)
            ,Kwh = SUM((DATEDIFF(DAY, c.FromDate, c.ToDate) + CONVERT(INT, c.FirstCharge)) * c.EstimatedAnnualConsumption / 365.0)
            --,UnbilledSupplies = COUNT(DISTINCT s.ElectricitySupplyID)
            ,UnbilledSupplies = isnull(COUNT(DISTINCT s.ElectricitySupplyID), 0)



     FROM   Sinq.staging.StandingChargeArchive c
            INNER JOIN Sinq.dbo.ElectricitySupply s
                ON s.ElectricitySupplyID = c.ElectricitySupplyID

    WHERE c.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

    GROUP BY c.CreatedDate --,s.ElectricitySupplyID
    --s.ProfileClass, c.BillingTier
),

Unbilled2 AS 
(
Select * , LAG(UnbilledSupplies) OVER(ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS UnbilledSuppliesPreviousMonth
FROM Unbilled
)
```

And it is returning the following for Unbilled supplies, when it should show for example -7.582938

```
0   0   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
211 0   1
195 211 0
180 195 0
218 180 0
281 218 0
315 281 0
206 315 0
69  206 0
38  69  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is integer division.  Try this:

```
COALESCE( (b.BilledSupplies - b2.BilledSuppliesPreviousMonth) * 100.0 / 
          NULLIF(b2.BilledSuppliesPreviousMonth, 0), 0
        )
```

I prefer `COALESCE()` to `ISNULL()` (because `COALESCE()` is standard SQL).  However, the important change is the `100.0`.  This changes the division to use decimal points, so `1 / 2` is `0.5` rather than `0`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the above really helped me! Alas I'm less than 15 reputation so I can't upvote this!

Comment: @Wil-Liam . . . You *can* (and should) accept answers to the questions that you ask.

Comment: This is where I show how much of a fool I am....How do you do this!? All I can see is 'Answer your question'!

Comment: Just realised I could click on a tick to answer! Thanks